# Can you share the lease collection for Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If we have the following:

- 1 Azure Cosmos DB account
- 4 databases
- Each database contains 1 collection

Would we be able to add 1 new database containing 1 new collection and use that collection as the lease collection for monitoring changes to the other 4 collections? Or does each lease collection need to be associated with 1 and only 1 monitored collection?

Answer (score 2):

Response from the Cosmos DB team (askcosmosdb@microsoft.com):

> You can share the Lease collection without issues. Depending on the activity on those 4 collections you might need to adjust the RUs on it though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Changefeedprocessor library stores the leases for each partition key range with the following identifier:

"id": "accountHostUrl_DatabaseResourceId_CollectionResourceId..PartitionNumber"

this makes it unique enough to use the same collection for storing leases for many collections across different databases, accounts.